# Detecting arithmetic overflow in C with NASM

Tags: c, integer, assembly

This snippet is about detecting whether the carry flag is set or cleared. I work on Mac OSX, so my snippet supports Mac only.

First, we need a routine that does the job:

**func.s**:

```
global _read_carry_flag

_read_carry_flag:
    mov al, 0
    jnc end 
    mov al, 1
end:
    ret
```

(Try `nasm2 -f macho64 func.s` for compiling into an object file.)

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define A (2 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000)
#define B (1 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000)

extern bool read_carry_flag();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int32_t a = A;
    int32_t b = B;
    int32_t ret = a + a + b;

    printf("%d\n", read_carry_flag());

    a = A;
    b = 1;
    ret = a + b;

    printf("%d\n", read_carry_flag());
    return 0;
}
```

(Try `gcc -o prog main.c func.o` for obtaining a process image.)

I would like to hear about possible improvements/extensions to the idea.

Comment: Hint: You can run nasm with --prefix_ and remove the '_' in front of the symbols. This way the code is prefix-agnostic and doesn't care about macho/elf/etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Wrong flag

I believe you should be looking at the overflow flag instead of the carry flag, since all of your operands are signed values.  On x86, the overflow flag is set if signed addition overflows.  The carry flag is set if unsigned addition overflows.

## Not reliable

As @Edward pointed out, it doesn't seem reliable to use this kind of function because you never know how the compiler is going to rearrange your code.  Even without the compiler rearranging your code, the results could be confusing.  From your own example:

```
ret = a + a + b;
overflow = read_overflow_flag();
```

Here, you are only detecting overflow over the second of the two additions.  If the first addition overflowed but the second didn't, you wouldn't catch it.  In other words, the assembly might look like this:

```
add %ecx, %edx, %edx  // ret = a + a  <- overflow not detected here
add %ecx, %ecx, %ebx  // ret = ret + b
seto %al              // overflow = overflow flag
```

To do it correctly, I would suggest you use a function that adds two numbers together and updates a cumulative overflow:

```
// If the add overflows, 1 will be added to *pOverflow.
int32_t add32_with_overflow(int32_t x, int32_t y, int *pOverflow);

int32_t ret      = 0;
int     overflow = 0;

ret = add32_with_overflow(a,   a, &overflow);
ret = add32_with_overflow(ret, b, &overflow);
printf("Overflow = %d\n", overflow);
```

Comment: "Wrong flag" Boom!

Comment: @coderodde This is over 3 years old, did you only read that part just now?

Comment: Not exactly. Just felt for a nice, warm comment.

Answer (score 5):

It can be made 2 bytes shorter by using the ADC instruction and avoiding the `jmp` (which should make it faster as well, but there's not much point to that in this case).

```
global _read_carry_flag

_read_carry_flag:
    mov al, 0
    adc al, 0
    ret
```

As @JS1 correctly points out in a comment, there's an even shorter method:

```
_read_carry_flag:
    setc al
    ret
```

A bigger issue is whether such a mechanism can be reliably used to detect overflow. It implicitly relies on the compiler to not generate any code that might alter the flag register after the addition is performed. That is likely to be true in this simple code, but it's not at all certain to me that one can generally rely on this.

Comment: I believe there is an even shorter way: `setc al`.  I agree with your concern about the reliability of such a function as a separate entity.  It would be best to actually perform the add inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

When adding 2 32-bits numbers and attempting to detect overflow,  code should be profiled against the most direct alternative.  An optimizing compiler will often make performance acceptable (and far easier to maintain) code.

```
int32_t a = A;
int32_t b = B;

// int32_t ret = a + a + b;
// printf("%d\n", read_carry_flag());

int64_t ret = (int64_t) a + a + b;
printf("%d\n", ret < INT32_MIN || ret > INT32_MAX);
```

Else, without going to wider types, code could use the highly portable:

```
// Does a+b overflow?
if (a >= 0) {
  if (b > INT32_MAX - a) Over();
} else {
  if (b < INT32_MIN - a) Under();
}
sum = a + b;
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible improvement in `read_carry_flag()`:

It might be worthwhile to either `xor` the `eax` register with itself before moving the return value into it, or just `mov` the return value into `eax` instead of `al` which will zero out the upper 32 bits of `rax`. The reason being the compiler may have used the `*ax` register before calling your function, and there could still be a value in there that will interfere with the return value of your function.

You pass the return value of your function directly to `printf()`. In x86-64 ABI, the first several integral arguments are passed in 8-byte registers, so the return value from `read_carry_flag()` will be passed in the `rsi` register. I don't know how exactly the compiler will move the return value into the register, but according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014188/1031545) the size of the `bool` type can be larger than one byte.

So if for example `sizeof bool == 2`, then the compiler can do:

```
call _read_carry_flags
mov rdi, formatString
mov si, ax
mov eax, 0
call printf
```

(The `mov eax, 0` instruction is needed to signal `printf()` that no further arguments are passed on the stack)

If `ax` had the value 0x100 before your function was called and your function executed

```
mov al, 0
```

After your function was called, `ax` would still contain the value 0x100 and that would be passed to `printf()` instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work at all. Signed overflow in your C code is undefined behaviour. You cannot rely on anything whatsoever once you have undefined behaviour. You need a check *before* you perform the operation and not perform the operation if it causes overflow.

You could write an assembler function "add_overflows" which takes A and B and tells you whether adding them will overflow. Doing that using inline assembler is probably better. And asking your compiler documentation if it has an intrinsic function for this is even better.

Or you do without assembler:

```
if (a >= 0 && b <= INT_MAX - a) { no overflow }
else if (a < 0 && b >= INT_MIN - a) { no overflow }
else { overflow }
```

Note that the way the code is arranged, there can be no overflow executing the code, but it tells you whether calculating a + b would overflow. If a >= 0 then we need to check that a + b <= INT_MAX, if a < 0 then we need to check that a + b >= INT_MIN.

Or shorter:

```
overflow = (a >= 0 ? b > INT_MAX - a : b < INT_MIN - a);
```

PS: For unsigned numbers, C subtracts UINT_MAX + 1 if the result is too large and doesn't call it overflow, but we can call it that. In this situation the result will be less than either of the summands. So you can write either of the following:

```
overflow = (a + b < a);
overflow = (a + b < b);
```

PPS: For signed integers, people used to observe that adding a positive number and getting overflow also gives a result less than the first numbers and wrote things like

```
if (a + 1 < a)
```

This doesn't work with aggressive compilers, which know that a + 1 is not less than a unless there is overflow, but overflow is undefined behaviour and can be assumed (wrongly but legally) to never happen, and change the condition to

```
if (FALSE)
```

There's your overflow check disappeared in thin air...